# neg. lookahead not working for postfix header

Tags: postfix, regex

I'm trying to exclude all emails not received from a mainstream domain
The full postfix regex in /etc/postfix/header_checks is:
`/Received:(?!.*\.((net|com|edu|gov|org|info)))/m DISCARD`

Bu the negative lookahead is failing to match longer header strings.
These longer header strings are seen in emails that are automatically forwarded from a gmail account (in the example below, forwarded from rocketman600@gmail.com to hello@mydomain.com):

```
Received: by 2002:a05:651c:98a:: with SMTP id b10mr2387341ljq.280.1630748063910;?        Sat, 04 Sep 2021 02:34:23 -0700 (PDT) from mail-lj1-f176.google.com[209.85.208.176]; from=<rocketman600+caf_=hello=mydomain.com@gmail.com> to=<hello@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f176.google.com>
```

is it something to do with the `;?`       part of the string?
I have no idea why its failing
thanks
MD

Comment: You mean to tell me you wish to silently disappear any mail that at some point was ever relayed by any host not spelling out its FQDN containing one of those TLDs? That sounds.. less like a reasonable practice and more like the result of a misunderstanding. What problem are you *actually* attempting to solve?

Comment: Re '...disappear ...any host not spelling out ...TLDs'? Well, yes, after an analysis of my mail header information. Cant cope with the spam despite max lookup services and a heap of regex already. Same email address in use 17 years now...has obviously been put around.

Comment: It looks like the regex is doing what you want. The string contains com, so it should fail to match.